# asp.net mvc file upload client side validator

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm looking for a client side validator for `input type="file"` to validate file names/extensions.

I know this is possible with jQuery validation, but would be nice to have this working as a validation attribute.

Comment: The way I've had to do it is to upload the file to the server, check the extension, then decide whether or not to keep it.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring this is what I'm doing currently but uploading a file (some of them are quite large) just to validate its extension is far from ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now such an attribute available in the [DataAnnotationsExtensions](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/) project.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a client side validation but you are referreing to a validation attribute which is a server side validation.

You should be validating submit on a client with jQuery and then on a server. Also do you really need an attribute for validating a file upload? How many action methods do you have that will be used for a file upload?

Comment: and how is this different to the built in "server side" validators like `RequiredAttribute` that generate client side validation by virtue of jQuery unobtrusive validation (hint - they are the same). In response to your question I have 5 different actions that allow file uploads, some that have multiple files. Therefore, an attribute will save a lot of duplication.

Comment: Agree regarding attribute saving code duplication - i didn't know whether it's a one off feature and whether it's really needed. Not following you regarding the first point, I'm still learning myself. Does MVC 3 supports unobtrusive validation for file upload controls?

Comment: Not OOTB. That's why I'm asking if anyone has created one :)

Comment: The validation attributes are great because validation is enforced server side and the correct jQuery client side validation is hooked up. If javascript is turned off you still get the enforcement server side. Additionally it's great to have it on a file upload as you can require that you choose a file and you can validate which file types are chosen.